# Codeigniter Update: Possible error in updating data, but does not display errors let alone update the data

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, updates

I want to edit some data on CodeIgniter. I have a data erase code structure like this:

CONTROLER

```
    public function submenu_edit($id_submenu)
{

    $sub_menu   = $this->menu_model->getSubmenu();

    $menu       = $this->db->get('menu_user')->result_array();

    $submenu    = $this->menu_model->detail_submenu($id_submenu);


    // validasi  

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required',
                               array('required' => 'Nama menu harus diisi',));

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('menu_id', 'Menuid', 'required',
                       array('required' => 'Nama menu harus diisi',));

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'Url', 'required',
                               array('required' => 'Nama menu harus diisi',));

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('icon', 'Icon', 'required',
                               array('required' => 'Nama menu harus diisi',));


   echo '1';


   if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
// End Validasi


    $data = array ( 'head_title'        => 'Menu Administrator - Edutech Solution',
                    'head_menu'         => 'Management Menu',
                    'title'             => 'Data Menu',
                    'sub_title'         => 'Total Menu',
                    'sub_menu'          => $sub_menu,
                    'menu'              => $menu,
                    'submenu'           => $submenu,
                    'isi'               => 'superadmin/administrator/submenu_edit'
                  );


    $this->load->view('superadmin/template/wrapper_admin', $data, FALSE);

    echo '2';

// Masuk Database
}else{
        $i  = $this->input;

        $data = array(  'id_submenu'    => $id_submenu,
                        'title'         => $i->post('title'),
                        'menu_id'       => $i->post('menu_id'),
                        'url'           => $i->post('url'),
                        'icon'          => $i->post('icon'),
                        'is_aktive'     => $i->post('is_aktive')
                     );

        $this->menu_model->edit_submenu($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Data Telah Diupdate');

        echo '3';

        // redirect(base_url('superadmin/administrator/submenu'),'refresh');
}
// End Masuk Database   

    echo '4';
}
```

I have a data erase code structure like this:
MODEL

```
public function detail_submenu($id_submenu) 
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('menu_sub');
    $this->db->where('id_submenu',$id_submenu); 
    $this->db->order_by('id_submenu');  
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row(); 
    
}


// Edit/ Update data
public function edit_submenu($data)
{
    $this->db->where('id_submenu', $data['id_submenu']);
    $this->db->update('menu_sub', $data); 

echo '5';
}
```

The problem is that when I edit, the data is not updated, but there is also an error message displayed.

but when I check the debug by adding echo '1' in each section, it reads "124".
maybe the problem is parts 3 and 5.

[Preview error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMnxa.jpg)

I have checked the code several times, but I found no errors. please help so that this problem can be resolved

Comment: *but there is also an error message displayed*: could you post the error message please?

Comment: also - it really pays off to use a php debugger. Its really easy to set up with vs code